# When running multiple scripts using another script, only the first script runs

Tags: bash, shell

I have two bash scripts that I usually run separately as:

```
for i in `cat sample_id.txt`;do qsub unicycler.sh ${i};done
for i in `cat sample_id.text`do qsub prokka.sh ${i};done
```

In order to run one after another I have created new bash script, ass_ann.sh, as:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 TEXT_ID=sampleid.txt
 for i in `cat path/to/file/${TEXT_ID};do qsub unicycler.sh ${i};done &&
 for i in `cat path/to/file/${TEXT_ID};do qsub prokka.sh ${i};done
```

According to the reading and search I have done, in order to run the script one after the other I only need to add `&&` at the end of the line. The first programme of the script, `unicycler.sh`, runs properly but the second, `prokka.sh`, doesn't run. `prokka.sh` gives the error `` `assembly.fasta' is not a readable non-empty FASTA file ``, which means that the prokka has tried to open the file when the fasta file has not been created yet. In turns, I think this means that the second programme is trying to run before the first finishes.

Can I have any suggestions on how I can I re-arrange the bash script so both `unicycler.sh` and `prokka.sh` run successfully, please?

Comment: Do you need to get all the unicycler ones done before all the prokka ones? Or is it ok to do unicycler 1 followed by prokka 1 then unicycler 2 followed by prokka 2?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, it could be either way, unicycler 1 follow by prokka 1 but the best probably will be to run first unicycler and then prokka. Unicycler is a software to assemble read, and prokka uses the assembly.fasta file from unicycler.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is a reasoning error here.

You try to start many tasks using the Torque resource manager on what seems like a powerful computer cluster. Unlike when you usually run a command in the shell, using the `qsub` command doesn't run the command right away. Instead, it sets up the task to be done later, and the command is considered done once the scheduling is finished, not necessarily when the command finished execution.

This clarifies why you might observe the second command starting before the first one has actually finished.

Typically, to check if a job is finished, you would query its status using `qstat`. `qstat` provides output if the job is running but fails if the job is already finished. The following example ensures that `command2` is executed after `command1` is finished:

```
jobid=$(qsub command1 arg1 arg2)
while qstat $jobid &>/dev/null; do sleep 10; done
qsub command2 arg1 arg2
```

However, in the use case you've provided, executing the jobs immediately is more desirable. Specifically, you're interested in combining the following commands into a single job:

```
$ unicycler.sh arg1 && prokka.sh arg1
```

This can be achieved with the following command:

```
$ sh -c "unicycler.sh arg1 && prokka.sh arg1"
```

So, you can write:

```
$ while read -r line; do qsub sh -c "unicycler.sh $line && prokka.sh $line"; done < path/to/file
```

Comment: I have written my script as follows: `#!/bin/bash \ PATH_TO_TEXT=path/to/files \ TEXT_ID=filename \ while read -r $1 ;do qsub sh -c "unicycler.sh $1 && prokka.sh $1"; done < ${PATH_TO_TEXT}/${TEXT_ID}`. But I get the error message `./unicycler_prokka_test.sh: line 7: /path/to/files/filename.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Ana, it is clear what the error is. Most likely you are attempting to open a file from the wrong directory. Try to give the full path name.

Comment: I have run { while read -r $line; do qsub sh -c "unicycler.sh $line && prokka.sh $line"; done < /path/to/file/filename.txt} but I get the following error Unable to read script file because of error: error opening sh: No such file or directory}. I can run the script separately with no problem and no errors

Comment: @Kvantoour, I usually run the script as `for i in `cat pathtofile/filename.txt`;do qsub scirpt.sh ${i};done`, and run perfectly. I tried to run the way you suggested from the terminal including whole path as `while read -r $line; do qsub sh -c "unicycler.sh $line && prokka.sh $line"; done < /home/myname/folder1/filefolder/filename.txt`, but I still get an error message: `Unable to read script file because of error: error opening sh: No such file or directory`.